# Excel 2003 Workbook Form Controls sometimes resize when viewed through a Virtual Machine

Tags: controls, excel, virtual-machine, excel-2003, vba

I develop for clients who are still using Excel 2003 on Windows XP systems. Therefore we develop within a Virtual Machine running XP and Office 2003.

I often create menu or control sheets within files using Form Control objects, mainly button controls. Sometimes when I open these workbooks up, the controls resize themselves (bigger, smaller and/or out of proportion). On occasions I have had a control that when you click it, it gets smaller and smaller.

If you save the file after this has occurred, the changes are kept the next time the workbook is opened.

The big concern is that this could occur on an end user machine as well if they ever migrated to a different version of Windows and used the designed sheets within a VM.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838006/en-us

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay in marking this. This seems to be the reason. We do have the service pack installed that they talk about but I think it is also related to running a VM that constantly resizes and therefore Excel doesn't know what space it is working off.